# Alphabetize strings (without using compareTo Method)

Tags: java, string, sorting, while-loop, compareto

I'm trying to sort an array of strings without using `compareTo()`, but I am getting stuck on my `while` loop. Is there a way to alphabetically sort strings without using `compareTo()` or `Arrays.sort()`?

```
public class mycode 
{

    public static void main(String[ ] args)
    {
            String[ ] ar = {"hello", "java", "elephant", "array"};
            mycode.display(ar);
            mycode.bubbleSort(ar);
            mycode.display(ar);
    }
    static void display(String[] ar)
    {
        System.out.println("***********************");
        for(int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(ar[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("***********************");

    }
    static void bubbleSort(String[] ar)
    {
        int theFollower;
        for(int currStart = 1; currStart < ar.length; currStart++)
        {
            theFollower = currStart;
            while(theFollower != 0 && ar[theFollower] < ar[theFollower - 1]) //this is where my problem is
            {
                String swap = ar[theFollower];
                ar[theFollower] = ar[theFollower - 1];
                ar[theFollower - 1] = swap;
                theFollower--;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Alphabetization is my goal, so my output would be the following

```
***********************
hello
java
elephant
array
***********************
***********************
array
elephant
hello
java
***********************
```

I added this method using the idea that was suggested, but I am unsure what I would put in place to run through the index of the string

```
    int alphabetize(String a, String b)
    {
    String A = a.toLowerCase();
    String B = b.toLowerCase();
    if (A < B)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (A > B)
    {
        return  1;
    }
    else
    {
    }
    }
```

Comment: You cannot use `<` and `>` on objects, only primitives. Do you have any ideas on what the algorithm should look like to do this without `compareTo`? Is this a homework assignment where using a library classes and functions would not be allowedd?

Comment: That's exactly what compareTo is for: know if an object is greater or smaller than another. Why would you NOT use compareTo()?

Comment: [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) is a substitute for `<, <=, ==, >=, >`. You *could* exactly re-implement this functionality yourself but why do you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @JBNizet Coding up something that's already in the JDK is a good programming exercise. It means that you have a model solution to consult when you've finished.

Comment: @chiastic-security I can agree with that, but if the solution was as simple as using `<` or `>` instead of compareTo(), there would not be much to reimplement, and we would have to wonder what the point of compareTo would be.

Comment: @JBNizet Or indeed what the point of the homework would be :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming this is homework, since the obvious way is just to use `compareTo()`, so I'll give you a hint on how to write your own method to do the comparison. You want something with signature

```
int compareStrings(String s, String t);
```

that returns `-1` or `0` or `1` depending on whether `s` is alphabetically before, equal to or after `t` in the alphabet.

Go through the two `String`s character by character, and at each stage, if the character from `s` is less than that of `t` (here you can use `<`) then return `-1`; if it's greater, then return `1`; if they're equal, keep going.

If you run out of characters in `s` but still have some in `t`, then return `-1`, and if it's the other way round then return `1`. If you run out of both at the same time, return `0`.

Comment: so I would use .charAt(0)?

Comment: @desireToLearn You'd have an index `i` that keeps moving through the `String`s, and you'd look at `.charAt(i)` from the two `String`s. After each comparison where they're equal, then increase `i` by 1. Take care to check at each stage whether you've overrun the end of the `String`, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this program by creating another function to compare each characters successively. It breaks when two characters are found to be unequal. Like, "Tony" and "Toby", after comparing 't' and then 'o' it compares 'n' and 'b' giving "Toby" to be less than "Toby" and then breaks. For a string contained in another like "Max" and "Maxwell" it puts the shorter one being less.

In my program I have asked the user to input names and then I sort it in descending alphabetical order. The function returns whether the first string is *lessThan* (not the '<') the first and thus swaps the two if it is.

I assume you understand bubble sort algorithm, so I am not explaining it. Feel free to ask me if you do not understand that.

```
/**
 * To sort twenty names in descending order using Bubble sort algorithm
 * This program does not use the compareTo method of the String class
 */

import java.util.Scanner;

public class NameBubbleSort {

    /*
     * function to find whether first string comes before second one in
     * alphabetical order
     */
    static boolean lessThan(String s1, String s2) {
        boolean flag = false;
        int i, lim;
        String shorter;
        // converting strings to lower case
        String first = s1.toLowerCase(), second = s2.toLowerCase();
        // finding shorter string setting iteration limit to its length
        if (first.length() <= second.length()) {
            shorter = first;
            lim = first.length();
        } else {
            shorter = second;
            lim = second.length();
        }
        // comparing successively each character one by one if they are same
        for (i = 0; i < lim; i++)
            if (first.charAt(i) != second.charAt(i)) {
                if (first.charAt(i) < second.charAt(i))
                    flag = true;
                // breaks the loop since the characters are unequal
                break;
            }
        // condition if one name is contained in another
        // eg. Peter Steve and Peter Stevens
        if (i == lim && first == shorter)
            flag = true;
        return flag;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String t;
        String[] name = new String[20];
        System.out.println("Enter 20 names: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            name[i] = in.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 19 - i; j++)
                // compares two adjacent strings and exchanges them if not in
                // correct order
                if (lessThan(name[j], name[j + 1])) {
                    t = name[j];
                    name[j] = name[j + 1];
                    name[j + 1] = t;
                }
        // printing the names
        for (String i : name) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        in.close();

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace your while with this :

```
while(theFollower != 0 && ar[theFollower].compareTo(ar[theFollower - 1]) < 0)
```

You cannot compare object with basic operator. `compareTo` is here to do this job.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)

Comment: I want learn to sort strings alphabetically without the use of .compareTo

Comment: I guess you have to rewrite the function so. Take a look on `String` source code. Basically, you have to compare the String, one character after another.