# Equivalent for function compareTo

Tags: java

I have an ask, I would like to know if it's possible to get an equivalent to replace `compareTo` ?

Here is an example:

```
if (stringArray[j - 1].compareTo( stringArray[j] ) > 0) {
```

**Edit**

I would like to sort my names to ameliore my knowledge.

```
String[] tab = {"soufiane", "amelia", "salma"};

public static void triBulle(String[] stringArray) {
        int n = stringArray.length;
        String temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {
                if (stringArray[j - 1].compareTo( stringArray[j] ) > 0) {
                    temp = stringArray[j - 1]; 
                    stringArray[j - 1] = stringArray[j];
                    stringArray[j] = temp; 
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What type is stringArray? (I know as it's called "stringArray" it's probably "String[] stringArray", just making sure). And why do you want to use an alternative?

Comment: Short answer: **Yes** Long answer: What type is `stringArray`, and how do you want to compare the strings (for the sake of argument) if not by compareTo? What have you tried? If this is working code, why do you want to change it?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to sort an array of `String` ?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Huh? Comparing two Strings with ">" does not work

Comment: Why would you want another method to do the **same** as the `compareTo` method? Why isn't `compareTo` good enough for you? Your question doesn't make any sense. Please **edit** the question and clarify what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Modus Tollens: it's an array with several names. I want to sort these names. I would like to know another alternative.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch: It's  just out of curiosity? I have edited my first message.

Comment: So you want to sort an array of Strings? `Arrays.sort(stringArray);`

Comment: @Modus Tollens: Indeed ! I would like to avoid `compareTo` method to improve my knowledge in algorithmic.

Comment: @joel Nice! So that's your answer then. Use Arrays.sort() to sort your string array.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking us to re-implement `String.compareTo(String)` for you. That is not something we will do in its entirety, nor is it really a question. The actual question you asked is answered by implication, it is possible to write your own function to compare two `String` instances.

Comment: @Modus Tollens: In my exercice, I have to use only `sort Bubble` method. I have succeeded. but I would like to do without `compareTo` method.

Comment: @joel So it's a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26789205/1288408 (can't vote to close as different dupe than before)